# Unable to access mongoodb database from heroku application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, mongoose, mern

Hii all I am working on simple mern application and I know it will be silly question for all great developers but in my mern application which is taking post and get data well when I run on my localhost but when I host it on heroku, initially it is working perfectly but after some time it is not able to get and post request.

> Index.js :

```
const express = require("express"); 
const mongoose = require("mongoose"); 
const cors  = require("cors"); 
const usersRouter = require("./routes/users"); 
const exercisesRouter = require("./routes/exercises"); 
const app = express(); 
require("dotenv").config();
const path = require("path");

 
app.use(cors()); 
app.use(express.json()); 

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING, 
{useNewUrlParser : true}).then(() => console.log("Database is Connected"))
    .catch(err => console.log("error occcured"));
    
   
  

app.use("/users", usersRouter); 

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
     res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}
// app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "./client/build")));

// app.get("*", function (request, response) {
//   response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "./client/build", "index.html"));
// });


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000; 

app.listen(PORT , () => { 
  console.log(`app is running on :${PORT}`); 
});
```

> Package.json :

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "client-build": "cd client && npm run build",
        "client-install": "cd client && npm install",
        "heroku-postbuild": "npm run client-install && npm run client-build",
         "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.3.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.17.3"
}
}
```

> And I am using Axios in fronted as :

```
axios.post('https://workouttrackergoal.herokuapp.com/add', user)
```

Can anyone plz tell me :).

Answer (score 1):

> I am answering to my question I feel maybe someone may face same issue
> in future so they can solve it with this easy steps:

1. You have to go heroku site and clicked the option on your created app.
2. Now their you have to go setting option and add your .env keys and values in the config field.
3. Be make sure you are taking correct path from axios like what I have done.
4. If the app still not displaying the database material then go to heroku again and your will see "more" tab on right side where you have to restart dynos.

Hope you may get the the desired result.